# Python - How to run cx_Freeze on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, cx-freeze

I would like to know how to run my `setup.py` script on Linux. I've done this on Windows by placing the setup script and the program script (and it the files it uses) in the Python33 directory on the C:\ drive. However, Linux is obviously different. I tried placing the setup script in the `/usr/bin/` directory since that's where Python3.3 is installed?

Linux is confusing me and I would very much like to create an exe of my program for Linux.

Comment: you may be well over your head here, as while linux does take binary files, they are not in the .exe format. Generally speaking porting application from one environment to another is not an easy task and requires at least basic understanding of both systems.

Comment: Oh, I thought cx_Freeze was multi-platform unlike py2exe and others?

Comment: It is promoted a "should" be cross platform, not as is. If you rely on certain dll/so then it is not going to work out of the box. You also must have the same python version as on windows box, which may not be trivial.

Comment: The Python version isn't a problem for me, since both Windows and Linux are running 3.3. Is there another way of making a stand alone program with Python on Linux? I don't want it to be a program in which someone has to specifically download IDLE just to run it.

Comment: You will need to compile it on both systems and that still may wind up with dependencies issue. As I said building something that is cross-platform is not trivial. And just because it's 3.3 doesn't mean that it's the same - you may have to rebuild it from sources to exact same minor version and to ensure that headers are available.

Comment: The `setup.py` script doesn't need to be in any particular location, you can run it from wherever it's saved. But consider whether you really need to - it's more common on Linux to just distribute .py files, because Linux machines almost always have Python (and up to date distros increasingly have Python 3).